# QTimer.singleshot is causing the GUI to hangout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a table that shows the running processes, with a decorator to update these information. Using the decorator as in the code below, causes the GUI to hangs out every time the `singleshot` is called (every second).

Why the `singleshot` is causing the GUI to hangs, and how can I get better logic ?

```
# First create table
data = getProcesses()
tableWidget = QTableWidget()
Layout.addWidget(tableWidget)
fillTable(data, len(data['pid']), len(data), tableWidget)

# get the processes
    def getProcesses():
        allprocesses = {}
        for p in psutil.process_iter():
            try:
                if p.name().lower() in ["python.exe", "pythonw.exe"]: # console, window
                    with p.oneshot():
                        allprocesses.setdefault('pid', []).append(p.pid)
                        allprocesses.setdefault('memory(MB)', []).append(p.memory_full_info().uss/(1024**2))
                        allprocesses.setdefault('memory(%)', []).append(p.memory_percent(memtype="rss"))
                        allprocesses.setdefault('cpu_times(s)', []).append(sum(p.cpu_times()[:2]))
                        allprocesses.setdefault('create_time', []).append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(p.create_time()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                        allprocesses.setdefault('cpu(%)', []).append(p.cpu_percent()/psutil.cpu_count())
            except:
                continue
        del p
        return allprocesses

def updateInfo(data, table):
    try:
        table.clear()
        for p in psutil.process_iter():
            if p.pid in data['pid']:
                try:
                    with p.oneshot():
                        data['memory(MB)'][data['pid'].index(p.pid)]    = p.memory_full_info().uss/(1024**2)
                        data['memory(%)'][data['pid'].index(p.pid)]     = p.memory_percent(memtype="rss")
                        data['cpu_times(s)'][data['pid'].index(p.pid)]  = sum(p.cpu_times()[:2])
                        data['cpu(%)'][data['pid'].index(p.pid)]        = p.cpu_percent()/psutil.cpu_count()
                        self.fillTable(data, len(data['pid']), len(data), table) 
                except:
                    continue
    except:
        pass                      

def tabledecorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(data, r, c, table):
        func(data, r, c, table)
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: self.updateInfo(data, table))            
    return wrapper

@tabledecorator
def fillTable(data, r, c, table):
    table.setRowCount(r) 
    table.setColumnCount(c)
    horHeaders = []
    for n, key in enumerate(reversed(sorted(data.keys()))):
        horHeaders.append(key)
        for m, item in enumerate(data[key]):
            newitem = QTableWidgetItem()
            newitem.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, item)
            table.setItem(m, n, newitem)
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)
    table.resizeColumnsToContents()
    table.resizeRowsToContents()
    del horHeaders, n, key, m, item, newitem
```

Comment: Your indentation mismatch and references to `self` clearly show that you're using a class, so please don't alter your code like that, as it makes it misleading and confusing. If you want to simplify your question, that's fine, but changing from a class to a more functional flow can change *a lot* of things, and you have to ensure that your problem is still reproducible, while making your code consistent. Besides, you're not using threads there, are you? And what's the point with all those `del`?

Comment: Have you tried simply placing the timer at the end of `fillTable`?

Comment: What @tromgy said, or even simpler: since you're clearly using a class, make the data and the table as instance members, remove the arguments of `fillTable`, and use a standard continuous timer connected to it, without making things unnecessarily complicated with decorators, wrappers, etc.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, I tried to simplify the code here, I might miss some changes. I tried the solution before, and used `QTimer(1000, ...)` in the class. But again, every time (every second) the table is cleared and filled again, the `window` hangs a bit. The purpose of this is to monitor specific python scripts I am running, instead of the ugly `task manger` of windows. Do I need to use a thread for this simple task, I don't wanna waste resources ?

Comment: @zezo for future reference, always ensure that you're providing a proper [mre]. Even if it's not expected to be *actually* reproducible, its contents *must* be consistent with your code, otherwise we might not understand if the problem is the actual implementation or your attempt to "reduce" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There various performance issues in your implementation, but the most important is that `fillTable` is called for ***all*** items.

Since that function is decorated with the timer, the result is that you will be calling a delayed `updateInfo` for *each* row in the table, and since that function *again* calls the decorated `fillTable`, you're actually having a *huge* recursion problem: at every new cycle, the number of function calls grows exponentially.

If you have 2 matching processes, the first time `updateInfo` is called it will call `fillTable` two times while creating two QTimers. After one second you'll have *two* calls to `updateInfo`, resulting in 4 calls (2 processes multiplied by 2 calls to `updateInfo`); after another second they will be 8, then 16 and so on.

Another problem with your code is that, at each call to `fillTable` you're calling three functions that should only be executed once for each cycle:

- `setHorizontalHeaderLabels`;
- `resizeColumnsToContents`;
- `resizeRowsToContents`;

The first one is pointless in *any* case, since the column labels will certainly *not* change through the lifetime of your program, and when that function is called it cycles through *all* its header items to check if any has changed.
The other two are very demanding in terms of performance, since the view is forced to query ***all*** items and call underlying functions to compute size hints of each row and column and then adapt the sizes accordingly.

There's really no point in using a single shot timer for this purpose, as the problem is that you're relying on function arguments to update the data, while a better approach is to properly use objects and references.

Other performance issues in your implementation:

- since the keys of the dictionary are known and won't change, there's no point in using `setdefault()`;
- you're constantly retrieving the *same* lists at each cycle;
- you're constructing the search list every time (which is time and memory consuming);
- some values are clearly constants, there's no need in computing/retrieving them at every cycle;

A possible reimplementation and simplification of your code could be the following:

1. create a normal QTimer in the `__init__`, which updates the process list (which might change for obvious reasons) and update it;
2. create an empty dictionary with all keys set as empty lists;
3. set the table with the predefined column count and horizontal labels;
4. create a function that cycles through the processes, if one already exists, update its data, otherwise create a new row and append the new data;
5. optimize the function to improve its execution time and memory usage;

```
CpuCount = psutil.cpu_count()
MemoryRatio = 1024 ** 2

class ProcView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 6)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.headers = 'pid', 'memory(MB)', 'memory(%)', 'cpu_times(s)', 'create_time', 'cpu(%)'
        self.updateColumns = 1, 2, 3, 5
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.headers)

        self.procTimer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=self.updateInfo)
        self.filter = 'python3', 'python'
        self.procs = {header:[] for header in self.headers}
        self.procTimer.start()
        self.updateInfo()

    def updateInfo(self):
        pids = self.procs['pid']
        memoryMb = self.procs['memory(MB)']
        memoryPerc = self.procs['memory(%)']
        cpu_times = self.procs['cpu_times(s)']
        create_times = self.procs['create_time']
        cpuPerc = self.procs['cpu(%)']
        for p in psutil.process_iter():
            if not p.name().lower() in self.filter:
                continue
            with p.oneshot():
                if p.pid not in pids:
                    row = len(pids)
                    self.table.insertRow(row)
                    pids.append(p.pid)
                    memoryMb.append(p.memory_full_info().uss / MemoryRatio)
                    memoryPerc.append(p.memory_percent(memtype="rss"))
                    cpu_times.append(sum(p.cpu_times()[:2]))
                    create_times.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(p.create_time()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                    cpuPerc.append(p.cpu_percent() / CpuCount)
                    for col, header in enumerate(self.headers):
                        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, self.procs[header][row])
                        self.table.setItem(row, col, item)
                else:
                    row = pids.index(p.pid)
                    memoryMb[row] = p.memory_full_info().uss / MemoryRatio
                    memoryPerc[row] = p.memory_percent(memtype="rss")
                    cpu_times[row] = sum(p.cpu_times()[:2])
                    cpuPerc[row] = p.cpu_percent() / CpuCount
                    for col in self.updateColumns:
                        item = self.table.item(row, col)
                        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, self.procs[self.headers[col]][row])

        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
```

Note that a proper implementation should possibly:

- avoid a dictionary with fields as keys and lists for each field, but eventually a dictionary with `pid` as keys and a dictionary for each item's field (a specialized class that works as an abstraction layer for the process would be even better);
- use a custom model (with a QTableView);
- verify whenever processes terminate;
- use fixed row sizes and avoid automatic column resizing at each cycle for *all* columns (it's better to use the `Fixed` resize mode for common fixed sized columns like the CPU usage and leave the resizing to the user);

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I believe the problem is in calling `for p in psutil.process_iter():` and `with p.oneshot()`, I believe they cause a block call to the last call of it. That's why, even with the better performance of your code, it still block the call

Comment: @zezo I successfully ran my code on Linux with more than 250 processes, and got no delay (I've a 8 years old CPU, by the way). It *is* possible that on Windows it behaves slightly differently, but unless you have an extremely high number of processes (and matching processes), the above should be pretty fast. Note that using a better object structure (as said, a dict of pids, instead of a dict of lists) will be even faster, especially if using a class (possibly with `__slots__` to improve performance) for each process. Also see [this](//stackoverflow.com/a/51995683) from the psutil author.

Comment: Obviously, moving the process retrieval to a thread would make things smoother on the UI side, but remember that widgets are not thread safe and you cannot access them from external threads. In order to communicate between threads you *must* use a QThread subclass with custom signals, and connect them with the UI update functions.